# GenStage.from_enumerable hangs with an intermitent stream

Tags: elixir, genstage

I have a stream which doesn't produce data as fast as its consumed.

So I have a producer defined like this:

```
def start_link() do
  create_stream
  |> GenStage.from_enumerable(name: Producer)
end
```

Then my producer-consumer subscribes to it

```
  def init(:ok) do
    {:producer_consumer, :the_state_does_not_matter, subscribe_to: [Producer]}
  end
```

And my consumer subscribes to mu producer-consumer

```
  def init(:ok) do
    {:consumer, :the_state_does_not_matter, subscribe_to: [ProducerConsumer]}
  end
```

The issue I am having is the consumer hangs, I think because at some point the producer didn't manage to get new data and as stated in the docs:

> When the enumerable finishes or halts, the stage will exit with
>   :normal reason. This means that, if a consumer subscribes to the
>   enumerable stage and the: cancel option is set to: permanent, which is
>   the default, the consumer will also exit with: the normal reason

So I read more and it suggests to add the option `cancel:: transient` to don't finish the stage. I added it like this but it's not working, am I missing something?

```
|> GenStage.from_enumerable(name: Producer, cancel: :transient)
```

Originally I was using a `Flow.into_stages(flow, [ProducerConsumer])` but I cant do that because I cant reference (or I don't know how) the ProducerConsumer from my supervisor tree

```
children = [
  {Producer, []},
  {ProducerConsumer, []},
  {Consumer, []}
]
```

**Update**

Updating passing reference to Flow.into_stages from the child definition

```
children = [
  {Producer, [name: ProducerConsumer]},
  {ProducerConsumer, []},
  {Consumer, []}
]

def start_link(producer_consumer) do
  create_stream
  |> Flow.into_stages(producer_consumer)
end
```

> ** (Mix) Could not start application test: Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown:
>   failed to start child: Producer
>       ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call({:name, ProducerConsumer}, {:"$subscribe", nil, #PID<0.2031.0>, [cancel: :transient]}, 5000)
>           ** (EXIT) no connection to Elixir.ProducerConsumer

Comment: Would not `{ProducerConsumer, [[name: ProducerConsumer]]}` (while specifying children) help to reference it by name `ProducerConsumer`?

Comment: mm and then use Flow.into_stages to use it?

Comment: For instance, seems like it should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldnt have to be {Producer, [[name: ProducerConsumer]]}?

Comment: Eh. What do you want to reference? Whatever it is, give it a name.

Comment: I updated my answer with the edit you suggested, it should work but I am receiving a no connection to ProducerConsumer error, but it should work

Comment: Well, I believe my suggestion was wrong then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> ** (Mix) Could not start application test: Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Producer **
>   (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call({:name, ProducerConsumer},
>   {:"$subscribe", nil, #PID<0.2031.0>, [cancel: :transient]}, 5000) **
>   (EXIT) no connection to Elixir.ProducerConsumer

Just means when the Flow.into_stages trying to sync to the provided consumer that consumer must already be running.

So, the order is important when supervising, something like this:

```
children = [
  Consumer,
  FlowProducerWorker # worker which implements Flow.into_stages(flow, [Consumer])
]
```